# pthreads to processes in c

Tags: c, multithreading, process, synchronization

I solved a synchron. project in C by threads (using pthread.h), but I found out I need to do it with processes. Is that going to be difficult to redo? I have approx. 4 hours, should I even try? I don't know much about processes.

Comment: Q: What is your OS?  Q: What compiler are you using?  What exactly does this "synchron. project" do?  Do your threads share data?  Is there any locking or signalling?

Comment: @FoggyDay it's just a very simple assignment for school (the river crossing problem). I'm on Linux and am using gcc 4.8 with the -std=gnu99 flag (and some -pedantic -Wall -Wextra stuff...)

Comment: If you're asking whether it is "easy", no. It, like all concurrency problems, is *tedious*. If you're asking "how" to do it while keeping as much code as you already have, you'll want to investigate (a) POSIX process shared memory, and (b) the mechanics for storing thread synchronization objects in said-shared memory. Its doable, but your threaded code has better be *solid* if you stand any chance of pulling this off in a few hours. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the problem and how you communicate between the threads.

If the threads are independent and don't require any communication, you can just use processes instead of threads. If there is a lot of communication and locking, it will be more difficult, of course. Then you must look into [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) like shared memory and semaphores.